# Value is not a member of Object when trying to pass dynamic variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, variables, aws-glue

I've got the following code

```
val region = envArgs("region")

// create a client object of class AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient
val client: AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient = new AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient().withRegion(Regions.region)
```

Region here is a dynamic variable that's passed in the arguments of the glue job. However, with this code I get the following error

```
value region is not a member of object com.amazonaws.regions.Regions    
val client: AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient = new AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient().withRegion(Regions.region)
```

Obviously its just trying to find the string "region" in Regions, how can I force it to instead search for the variable?

Comment: Nah its super annoying, but it needs to be .withRegion(Regions.region) because the Regions list imports a Region object that's specified with the region name.

Comment: The hardcoded way to do this would be 

withRegion(Regions.US-EAST-1)

Comment: @MarioGalic OP believes he / she can uses an arbitrary string as a method name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A previous poster deleted their answer, but I was able to get this working with the following

```
val client: AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient = new AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient().withRegion(Regions.getCurrentRegion)
```

Comment: The previous poster explained what I was trying to do was not possible in a statically typed language like scala. Idk why they deleted their post, but hopefully this is helpful to someone